# How can I element-wise 2 Tensors with different dimensions with Broadcasting?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor called `inputs` with a `size` of `torch.Size([20, 1, 161, 199])` and another `mask` with a size of `torch.Size([20, 1, 199])`. I want to multiply them together.

I tried:

```
masked_inputs = inputs * mask[..., None]
```

but get an error:

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (161) must match the size of tensor b (199) at non-singleton dimension 2
```

I'm not quite sure what to do?

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it:

```
masked_inputs = inputs * mask.unsqueeze(2)
```